# NodeJS xmpp server

Tags: node.js, xmpp

I make the first steps in the node js and xmpp

I need to run at xmpp server on node js for messaging

Here's the process:
I use node-xmpp server https://github.com/astro/node-xmpp
run the example of a server (/examples/c2s.js)
join to server with two clients (clients tested on other servers jabber - it works and the messages are sending through)

Clients have authorization on my server.
But when I send a message from one client to another, the message comes to the server (I see it in the logs)
and that was the message does not come to recipient

I don `t know where to look for the problem
server configuration ? routing ? messaging may be necessary to add yourself ?

help me plz

my server code (by examples)

```
var xmpp = require('../lib/node-xmpp');

var c2s = new xmpp.C2SServer({
    port: 5222,
    domain: 'localhost'

});

// On Connect event. When a client connects.
c2s.on("connect", function(client) {
    c2s.on("register", function(opts, cb) {
        console.log("REGISTER");
    cb(true);
    });

    client.on("authenticate", function(opts, cb) {
        console.log("AUTH" + opts.jid + " -> " +opts.password); 
    cb(null); 
    });

    client.on("online", function() {
        console.log("ONLINE");
        client.send(new xmpp.Message({ type: 'chat' }).c('body').t("Hello there, little client."));
    });

    client.on("stanza", function(stanza) {
        console.log("STANZA" + stanza);

    });

    client.on("disconnect", function(client) {
        console.log("DISCONNECT");
    });

});
```

I run a server and connect to it by this code

```
var xmpp = require('../lib/node-xmpp');
var argv = process.argv;

if (argv.length < 6) {
    console.error('Usage: node send_message.js <my-jid> <my-password> <my-text> <jid1> [jid2] ... [jidN]');
    process.exit(1);
}

var cl = new xmpp.Client({ jid: argv[2], password: argv[3] });

cl.addListener('online',
   function() {argv.slice(5).forEach(
       function(to) {cl.send(new xmpp.Element('message', { to: to,type: 'chat'}).c('body').t(argv[4]));
       });

       // nodejs has nothing left to do and will exit
       // cl.end();
   });

cl.addListener('stanza',
    function(stanza) {
        if (stanza.is('message') &&
            // Important: never reply to errors!
            stanza.attrs.type !== 'error') {
            console.log("New message");
            // Swap addresses...
            stanza.attrs.to = stanza.attrs.from;
            delete stanza.attrs.from;
            // and send back.
            cl.send(stanza);
        }
    });

cl.addListener('error',
    function(e) {
       console.error(e);
       process.exit(1);
   });
```

Comment: Please post the problematic code, otherwise we have no information and will just be guessing!

Comment: You're replacing the to with the from prior to sending?

Answer (score 5):

The short answer: change `cb(null)` to `cb(null, opts)`.

The long answer:

1. `client.on("authenticate", function(opts, cb) {...})` registers what the server will do when the client tries to authenticate itself. Inside node-xmpp, it will look for the authentication mechanism first and the mechanism will then call the callback and retrieve the authentication results via `cb`.
2. By default, the `Plain` authentication is used. You can check out how it works here: https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-xmpp-server/blob/master/lib/authentication/plain.js. With Plain the `opts` stores the jid and password.
3. Then to inform node-xmpp that authentication failed/sucessed, we need to look into `mechanism`, https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-xmpp-server/blob/master/lib/authentication/mechanism.js, inherited by Plain.

       `this.authenticate(this.extractSasl(auth), function (err, user) {
           if (!err && user) {
               self.success(user)
           } else {
               self.failure(err)
           }
       })`

   Here, `cb` requires two parameters. When `err` is null and `user` is non-null, it indicates authentication successes. Otherwise, failed.

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert on neither node.js nor xmpp. But reading your code. I assume the "stanza" is the event where a client sent a message. You asked it to log the message, but you gave no instructions on how to route it to the recipient. You should break down the received message on the server into message body and recipient, and ask your server to send it to the recipient.

Answer (score 1):

Alex you have used C2SServer which connects a stream between a server and a client. When you send a  message from one client to another they get to server. Now its responsibility of the sever to relay them back to actual receiver.

One possible solution is to keep client object is a global object corresponding to their jids when client is authenticated, when you get a message for that client you can get that from global variable and route the message to actual client kept in global variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the text message & receiver JID from server. Just break the stanza in following ways and put this before error listeners:-

```
cl.on('stanza', function(stanza) {
   if (stanza.is('message') && (stanza.attrs.type !== 'error')) {
       var body = stanza.getChild('body');
       if (!body) {
         return;
       }
       console.log(stanza.attrs.from+" Says: "+body.children[0]);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In "authenticate", may an argument not be enough for a callback?

```
NG:
cb(null);

OK:
cb(null, opts);
```